# Creation of a mean function

Tags: list-manipulation, probability-or-statistics

Hello I just started using Mathematica, and I want to create a mean function without using the built-in command.

I did that so far, but the code is not running :

```
mean[list_] := (
  For[i = 0, i < Length[list], i++,
   mean = (Sum[list[n], {n, 1, i}])/Length[list]])
```

If anyone has an idea, thanks for the future help.

Comment: I suppose the `For` loop isn't really necessary, since `Sum` adds up over the list.  You could use `Total`: `mean[list_] := Total[list]/Length[list]`

Comment: Thank a lot for you help !

Comment: I think `f[_]:="I am going to bite you"` is a pretty mean function (just saying).

Answer (score 5):

There are a few things wrong with your code:

```
mean[list_] := (
  For[i = 0, i < Length[list], i++,
   mean = (Sum[list[n], {n, 1, i}])/Length[list]])
```

Let's clear the incorrect definition:

```
Clear[mean]
```

1. You do not need the parenthesis around the For[] loop since this is the only command:

```
mean[list_] := For[i = 0, i < Length[list], i++, mean = (Sum[list[n], {n, 1, i}])/Length[list]]
```

2. You are defining a function `mean[list_]`, but you also redefine `mean` inside your function. That will not work, so let's call the other one `mean2`:

```
mean[list_] := For[i = 0, i < Length[list], i++, mean2 = (Sum[list[n], {n, 1, i}])/Length[list]]
```

3. A `For` loop does not return a value in the Wolfram Language. I think you want to return `mean2` here, so let's add that. This turns the function into multiple statements which are separated by a semi-colon. Also because we now have multiple statements we need to use parenthesis:

```
mean[list_] := (
 For[i = 0, i < Length[list], i++, mean2 = (Sum[list[n], {n, 1, i}])/Length[list]];
 mean2)
```

4. Since `mean2` and `i` are local temporary variable it is best to declare them as such using a `Module`:

```
mean[list_] := Module[{mean2,i},
 For[i = 0, i < Length[list], i++, mean2 = (Sum[list[n], {n, 1, i}])/Length[list]];
 mean2
]
```

5. Another programming error is the use of `list[n]` where you mean to use `list[[n]]` (which is the short notation for `Part[list,n]`):

```
mean[list_] := Module[{mean2,i},
 For[i = 0, i < Length[list], i++, mean2 = (Sum[list[[n]], {n, 1, i}])/Length[list]];
 mean2
]
```

6. At this point you have something that approaches normal code, however it gives the wrong answer, because the For loop stops when `i` is one less than the length of the list.
   You can fix that by using <= instead of < . Also list indices start with 1 in the Wolfram Language:

```
mean[list_] := Module[{mean2,i},
 For[i = 1, i <= Length[list], i++, mean2 = (Sum[list[[n]], {n, 1, i}])/Length[list]];
 mean2
]
```

7. At this point you get the right answer, but you are doing too much computational work. Specifically you are computing `mean2` many times, but only the last one gives the mean value. So the whole For loop is not required. And when you remove the For loop you also don't need the temporary variables and you also don't need the Module, so it becomes just:

```
mean[list_] := Sum[list[[n]], {n, 1, Length[list]}] / Length[list]
```

8. A simpler way to sum the elements of a list is to use Total:

```
mean[list_] := Total[list] / Length[list]
```

9. Or more directly you can use `Mean`:

```
mean[list_] := Mean[list]
```

10. If you really want to use a `For` loop, you can use something like this:

```
mean[list_] := Module[{total = 0},
  For[i = 1, i <= Length[list], i++, total += list[[i]]];
  total/Length[list]
  ]
```

(Note that in the Wolfram Language lists are indexed starting with 1, not 0.)

Answer (score 2):

Two variations based off your code

```
mean[list_] := Module[
  {accumulator = 0, len = Length[list]},
  For[i = 1, i <= len, i++,
   accumulator += list[[i]]];
  accumulator/len]

Clear[mean]

mean[list_] :=
 Sum[list[[i]], {i, 1, Length[list]}]/Length[list]
```